# como incluir a fonte de vídeo usando javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, vídeo

como incluir a fonte de vídeo usando javascript sem imprimir o código final no navegador (com o inspetor de elementos)? Eu estive pensando sobre várias maneiras, mesmo julgando atualmente impossível, mas gostaria que a opinião de vocês sobre isso. Eu uso um player personalizado com css feito por mim mesmo, e eu não posso usar o flash.

Comment: O que queres dizer com "a fonte de vídeo"? a `font` do texto? ou o `url` do video?

Comment: Você quer embedar um vídeo cuja origem não possa ver vista de forma alguma ?

Comment: fonte = source
sim, aplicar talvez algum token ou qualquer coisa que só permita que meu site visualize. Só a ideia ajudaria =P 
mas uma orientação me tornaria um fã da pessoa kkkk =P

Comment: Essa pergunta já tem um certo tempo, mas lendo ela tive uma ideia: aplicar o conceito de [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) em seu serviço que fornece o vídeo, permitindo apenas requisições de seu próprio domínio, isso talvez poderia lhe ajudar a resolver o problema de terceiros utilizarem seu vídeo?

Comment: Ideia interessante Fernando, vlw =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu penso que não seja possível fazer com que o URL do vídeo não apareça no código fonte quando o elemento é inspecionado, mas sempre podes ofuscar o código tornando-o mais difícil de ser lido a olho-nu usando ferramentas como o [Source Code Encrypter](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm) etc.

Um código normal que seria:

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Irá ficar da seguinte maneira:

```html
<script>
<!--
document.write(unescape("%3Cvideo%20width%3D%22400%22%20controls%3E%0A%20%20%3Csource%20src%3D%22http%3A//www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4%22%20type%3D%22video/mp4%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Csource%20src%3D%22http%3A//www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg%22%20type%3D%22video/ogg%22%3E%0A%20%20Your%20browser%20does%20not%20support%20HTML5%20video.%0A%3C/video%3E"));
//-->
</script>
```

No entanto como podes ver, se reparares bem ainda consegues ver a origem/URL do vídeo mas podes dificultar ainda mais um pouco as coisas, como por exemplo usar serviços de encurtamento de URLs como o `goo.gl` ou o `bit.ly` para que o URL se passe por despercebido no meio de todo esse código ou criar um URL apenas para hospedagem de videos que não seja tão óbvio, como por exemplo o Twitter utiliza o `t.co`, se usares um URL do mesmo estilo ele não vai chamar tanta atenção quando encriptado juntamente com o resto do código.

Exemplo de domínio: `http://0.me` que irá ser - `0.me/meuVideo.mp4` ou `0.me/g16dfs.mp4`.

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cvideo%20width%3D%22400%22%20controls%3E%0A%20%20%3Csource%20src%3D%22http%3A//0.me/g16dfs.mp4%22%20type%3D%22video/mp4%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Csource%20src%3D%22http%3A//0.me/g16dfs.mp4%22%20type%3D%22video/ogg%22%3E%0A%20%20Your%20browser%20does%20not%20support%20HTML5%20video.%0A%3C/video%3E"));
```

Ou ainda podes aumentar a quantidade de código a ser encriptado para dificultar a leitura. Contudo sempre pode chegar alguém e desencriptar o código usando ferramentas do desenvolvedor. Então isto apenas será mais efectivo para aqueles que não percebem muito de código ou que são iniciantes na área do desenvolvimento web.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, creio que de fato, ainda, não há condições para oq eu gostaria, mas agradeço as sugestões. =)