# Proteger uri do player de conteúdo

Tags: html, html5, vídeo, reprodutor-de-video

Seguinte, gostaria de utilizar algum componente de *player* em html que não apresentasse a uri de acesso ao conteúdo em execução.

Alguém já viu algum esquema que renderiza um *player* no navegador, mas quando alguém inspecionar o elemento, a fonte do ficheiro não seja apresentada, uma proteção de conteúdo como o Spotify tem.

Comment: Amigo, não sei se ia adiantar. Eu consigo interceptar o carregamento de uma mídia, simplesmente abrindo o console do Google Chrome, clicando em `network` e filtrando por `mídia`.

Comment: possível duplicata de [como incluir a fonte de vídeo usando javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65846/como-incluir-a-fonte-de-v%c3%addeo-usando-javascript)

Comment: Bom dia pessoal, obrigado pelos comentários, encontrei o que preciso [AQUI](http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php). E chun o post q vc informou sendo duplicata, não ficou bom pra mim a resposta, mto simples.

Comment: Perdão não simple*, mas sempre encontramos solução...rsrsrs

Comment: @Chun, abri uma pergunta no Meta para discutir esta aqui. [Pergunta canônica para Media Source Obfuscation](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4390/201)

Comment: Um link apenas não se consolida como resposta. Se você encontrou uma resposta para sua pergunta, crie uma resposta para sua pergunta, transpondo o que você encontrou. Um link pode ser perder, a página do link pode ficar off-line e sua pergunta sem resposta.

Comment: Se você tem o intuito de não permitir que terceiros utilizem seu vídeo, talvez uma alternativa seja utilizar o mecanismo de [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) em seu serviço que fornece o vídeo (se o serviço é seu =D), permitindo apenas requisições de seu próprio domínio, isso talvez poderia lhe ajudar a resolver o problema de terceiros utilizarem seu vídeo?